# PySimpleGUI: Set and get the cursor position in a multiline widget?

Tags: python, position, cursor, textfield, pysimplegui

Is there a way to get the position of the cursor in a multiline widget in PySimpleGUI, storing it and putting the cursor back again on a defined position in the text of that widget?

Below you see the code I wrote so far. My aim is that when "jk" in typed in the upper window then the cursor goes down to the input line (that works). There the user can write a command and finish the input pressing  (that I have not done yet).

The question is now how to make the cursor jump back in the upper window on the same position where it was before?!

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Multiline(key = 'editor',
                          size = (50, 10), 
                          focus = True, 
                          enable_events = True)],
            [sg.InputText(key ='command', size = (45, 1), ),], ]

window = sg.Window('editor', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if 'jk' in values['editor']:
        # delete jk and jump down in the command line #
        window['editor'].update(values['editor'].replace('jk', ''))
        window.Element('command').SetFocus(force = True)
        
    if event in ('Close Window', None): 
        break
    
window.close()
```

Any help is appreciated as the is no documentation about setting or getting cursor position in PySimpleGui. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tkinter code required here.

- Using method `delete`of tkinter Text widget, `element.widget`, to remove the input `jk`.

  - `'insert'` is the position of the insertion cursor in the text widget.
  - `'insert-2c'` step back 2 characters, with `'insert'` it mark the area to delete.

> delete(index1, index2=None)
> Deletes text starting just after index1. If the second argument is omitted, only one character is deleted. If a second index is given, deletion proceeds up to, but not including, the character after index2. Recall that indices sit between characters.

- Method `set_focus` of element sets the current focus to be on this element.
- Method `mark_set` of the Text widget to set the position of insert cursor.

> mark_set(mark, index)
>
> If no mark with name mark exists, one is created with tk.RIGHT gravity and placed where index points. If the mark already exists, it is moved to the new location. This method may change the position of the tk.INSERT or tk.CURRENT indices.

- chapter 24.1 Text widget indices show the wat to specify a position in the content of a `Text` widget or `Multiline` element.

Refer: https://tkdocs.com/shipman/tkinter.pdf

Example code show how it work, "jk" to jump from "M1" to "M2", and  key to jump back from "M2" to "M1".

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(40, 5), enable_events=True, key='M1')],
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(40, 5), key='M2')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

m1, m2 = window["M1"], window['M2']
m2.bind("<Return>", "_Return")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "M1" and 'jk' in values["M1"]:
        m1.Widget.delete("insert-2c", "insert")
        m2.set_focus()
    elif event == "M2_Return":
        m1.set_focus()
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Comment: The original question was: _get the position of the cursor in a multiline widget in PySimpleGUI, storing it and putting the cursor back again on a defined position_ Is this happening here? And if so, how? A few more comments are called for, imo..

Comment: Updated as above.